PostgreSQL query scanning all partitions instead of specific one when filtering on dimention table
I have two tables in PostgreSQL, one large (transactional) with millions of data which is partitioned on column TenantId and one smaller (dimension) which has TenantId and TenantName columns, I have joined the tables using the column TenantId. When I filter the join on TenantId then only proper partition is scanned but when i filter the join on TenantName all partitions are scanned.
Notes:

I use PostgreSQL v16.
I use inheritence partitioning with check condition on equality of TenantId (uuid).
This is an inditect filtering as TenantName corresponds only to one TenantId in the smaller table.

The simple test query:
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM datamiddleware."AftersalesStatistic" as a
INNER JOIN system.tenantinformation_int as b
ON a."TenantId"::uuid = b."tenantx_id" ::uuid
--WHERE b."tenantx_id" = 'a1234567-f4d1-4e06-9a4b-0b2132ab2fd4' --SCANS ONLY PROPER PARTITION
--WHERE b."tenantx_name" = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' --SCANS ALL PARTITIONS

Filtering with TenantId

Filtering with TenantName

Why?

It would be so much clearer with the actual, exact definition of involved tables (CREATE TABLE statements). And standard info for a [postgresq-performance] question.

You can try adding extended statistics for dependencies. This refers to what @Phil W is mentioning below. Or maybe you have already added these statistics but we can't tell from the information provided like Erwin wrote above.


When I filter the join on TenantId then only proper partition is scanned but when i filter the join on TenantName all partitions are scanned.

That's because TenantId is what the partition is defined on, so it's an ideal candidate for restricting what needs to be read.

... TenantName corresponds only to one TenantId in the smaller table.

But how does the database know this?
If it's not explicitly told about this 1:1 relationship, then it has no choice but to Table Scan across all the partitions to find any records that contain the TenantName.
